# Ionic cannot open facebook profile page from app

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to open Facebook's profile page that corresponds to a user in `ionic` application. I use `cordovaInAppBrowswer` plugin.

```
url = 'fb://profile/vahid.vdn';
var options = {
    location: 'yes',
    clearcache: 'yes',
    toolbar: 'yes'
};
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open( url, '_system', options ).then(function(event) {
    // facebook app is already installed and opened successfully 
})
.catch(function(event) {
    // facebook app isn't installed in this device
    url = 'https://facebook.com/vahid.vdn'
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open( url, '_system', options );
}
```

This just open Facebook's home page in the Facebook app. (Platform: **iOS**)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Facebook,

```
url = 'fb://profile?id=vahid.vdn';
```